# JAVA_ARGS для jenkins в контейнере docker

Tags: java, docker, jenkins

Имею контейнер с `jenkins`. Появилась необходимость добавить в конфигурацию

```
JENKINS_JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true"
```

чтоб включить `STARTTLS` для отправки почты. 
В самом контейнере не могу найти конфигурацию, как правильно это реализовать? 
Контейнер пересоздать не могу. 
Версия `jenkins 2.222.3`, взят из официального образа в [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins)

Comment: Судя по докерфайлу, для запуска используется /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh, можно попробовать отредактировать его, приаттачившись к контейнеру, и потом перезапустить его. Хотя правильный вариант - это все же пересоздать контейнер.

Comment: Если единственный верный путь пересоздать контейнер, как это сделать, чтоб не потерять инфу, которая есть в текущем?

Comment: Если при создании контейнера был смонтрован  volume /var/jenkins_home, то  вся конфигурация останется там. Иначе нужно смотреть куда оно все записало и делать правильно )

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file